# Working of sort() in c++ while sorting strings

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting, c++14

I was solving a problem, [QuestionsLink](https://www.hackerearth.com/practice/data-structures/arrays/1-d/practice-problems/algorithm/baaki-che/), where we are given a name along with an integer. You have to print three names with the maximum integer values.

So, I converted the number to a string and concatenated it before the names. After sorting I was getting desired results. But it failed some test cases which made me curious about how the sort function in c++ works.

Here is my code:

```cpp
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
#define ll long long int

using namespace std;

int main() {

  ll n;
  cin >> n;

  string names[n];
  int arr[n], digits[n];

  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    cin >> names[i] >> arr[i];
    names[i] = to_string(arr[i]) + names[i];
  }

  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    digits[i] = floor(log10(arr[i]) + 1);
  }

  sort(names, names + n, greater<string>());

  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    cout << names[i] << endl;
  }
  /*for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
     string s = names[i].substr(digits[i],names[i].length());
     cout<<s<<endl;
   }
   cout<<digits[98];
 */
  return 0;
}
```

Test cases:

```
9huDmy
995YnAYoAEE
990RUTM
96ipORo
956LNjFa
```

So, After sorting in descending order how is 9huDmy on top while the next two are sorted based on the digits in front of them.

Comment: The ASCII code of `'h'` (104) is bigger than the ASCII code of `'9'` (57) or of any other digit. That's why.

Comment: Don't use `#include <bits/stdc++.h>` ([Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095)), using low letter defines (`#define ll long long int`) can lead to many unexpected problems, use `using` instead (`using ll = unsigned long long;`). Dynamic size array (`string names[n]`)  are not standard c++ but an extension use std containers instead.

Comment: I would like to expand in @T.niese: Don't use the "competitive coding" environment for learning a language (any language). Competitive coding optimizes in all the wrong places, and DE-emphasizes those things you would WANT in a "real" program -- readability, maintainability, modularity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `greater<string>` sorts numbers as smaller than characters, based on their ASCII value.

You shouldn't've concatenated them in the first place.

1) Use `std::pair< int, std::string >` to group integers and strings.

2) Use `std::vector< std::pair< int, std::string > >`, not C arrays.

3) <del>Write a comparator functor (or lambda) that sorts pairs depending on their int value.</del> Comparing `std::pair` automatically compares their `.first` element, i.e. your integer values.

---

4) Use verbose `std::`, or `using std::string` etc, not `using namespace ...`, as your global namespace will get awfully crowded very fast.